# How to "regionalize" a Winform?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am in the process of translating one of our English applications into other languages.  I was wondering how one would go about getting the application to automatically decide, based on region and language settings, to display in either English or whatever other language we have?

For example I've just created .resx files for all existing forms in French (translated from English).  I now have 2 files - frmMyForm.vb and frmMyForm.fr-CA.vb.

Generally speaking, what would be the proper way to set this application up, using those resource files, to determine based on region settings which form to display (either frmMyForm.vb or frmMyForm.fr-CA.vb)?

Feel free to request additional information if that would help you help me.

Comment: Hard to make sense of this question, you *localize* a UI.  You have no lack of choices in the Language property dropdown, there are 14 versions of French.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm not trying to create a hard-coded approach. By using the drop down I have to specify one localization language.  I want the application to decide  which version of the forms to display (Either fr-CA or en-US for example).  I assumed resource files would be the best way to do this since we have someone else providing the translations - not Visual Studio.

Comment: That's entirely automatic, there is no point in helping.  If there is no satellite assembly for the user's preferred language then it automatically falls back.

Comment: Interesting.  I guess I can give this a try.  The reason I asked was because this is a legacy application from before I started my job here and from changing regional & language settings with Localizable set to True, nothing happens.  If you have the time to explain that process you mentioned in an answer I'd be happy to look it over and accept it if it works!  I'll start looking into it on my own just in case it's not worth your time.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shortly after asking the question I found a great Visual Studio tool that takes care of exactly what I was looking for. http://resxresourcemanager.codeplex.com/

Thanks to those who expended effort into this question, nonetheless!

Answer (score 1):

If you want the easy way. In Visual Studio UI, click on the form, set Localizable to True and set the Language you want. Then change all the text of your labels. Depending on the language selected, visual studio will create the proper resource.

When running the application, the right label will be displayed depending on the culture.

You could always set the text manually by pulling it from the resources like.

```
labelName.Text = ResourceClassName.ResourceName
```